# How to show an Alert Box in controller after performing some mathematical operation.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, alert

I want to display `Alert Box` after performing some mathematical operation inside `controller`.
I want to code it into controller, but how to do... till now i tried with:

```
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Total of Debit and Credit balance does not Tally');</script>");
return JavaScript("<script>alert(\"some message\")</script>");
return JavaScript("<script>alert(\"some message\")</script>");
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello world!');</script>");
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Data Already Exists');</script>");
return RedirectToAction("");
ViewBag.DataExists = true;
return RedirectToAction("");
```

All alternatives i tried...

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
return JavaScript(alert("Hello this is an Alert"));
```